# Best Approach to Copy a EF6 Generated Database from Test to Production

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have generated my database in Test using Code first using Entity Framework 6 with automated migrations.
I want to copy this entire database to Production now after truncating few transaction tables.
What is the best approach keeping in mind that I will have a DBA create the database for me in Production with the script I provide due to security restrictions and I want to continue using automated migrations.
I do not have a way to create the database in production using EF6, it has to be done by the DBA with the script that I provide.

**After creating the database in production:**

1. Copy _migrationHistory table from test to production, so that both the databases are at the same migration point. I assume that I don't have to do anything in this case.
2. After changing my connection string to new database in production, create an empty migration by removing all the code for new tables in up method manually(since database has already been created) and running update-database command. I assume, this will create _migrationHistory table in Production and I will be at the same migration level in test.

Or some other strategy that is more helpful and maintains migrations for me in production.

Thanks.

Comment: Entity framework has a way to generate migration scripts. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#getting-a-sql-script

Comment: thanks. but my _migrationhistory table is blank or doesn't exist yet but my Migrations folder inside VS has the migrations. Even if I use migration scripts, it is showing me to create all the tables inside the production database again.

Comment: Is the DBA creating the database only, or do all table changes need to go through the DBA? If the DBA is creating the database only (which I would assume, or else all migrations will need to go through DBA), you should be able to run `dotnet ef database update --project [PROJECT] --context [CONTEXT] --configuration [CONFIG]` to update to the latest migration in your project. You will not have to manually create _migrationHistory table, etc.

Comment: DBA is creating database,tables,SP etc. in production from a script with same name database in test. Any changes in table structure thereafter will be done by developers.

Comment: I would be unfamiliar with how to handle it at that point. There is no way to allow tables to be created this first time (and SP's, etc.)? What happens in the future when a new table is added? I'm not sure migrations is too helpful at that point if the DBA needs to run scripts, but there may also be functionality I am not aware of that would be helpful in this scenario.

Comment: It sounds like your DBA wants to have control over the scripts. You have to agree with them on how to manage this. Another approach can be to use just do your developments and use a schema comparison tool against the production database to generate a change script. Visual Studio has something built in.